# A non well formed numeric value encountered in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add two variables together.  I believe both contain an **integer**, but when I draw what is stored within `$product->mileage`, I receive the following error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

```
    $oilchange = $request->oilchange_at_kms;

    $product = Product::find($request->product_id);

    $mileage = $product->mileage; // Error within this variable, but it is an int

    $total = $mileage + $oilchange;
```

How can I test this, or how can I find the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually pops up when you try to add an integer with a string or some type of non numeric field.

You can test this by using the PHP `gettype()` method:

```
dump(gettype($product->mileage));
dd(gettype($oilchange));
```

If it turns out that one of these is a string (possibly from a form response), you can cast it to an `int` if you are certain that the value will always be an `int`.

```
 $mileage = (int)$product->mileage;
```

Not really recommending this, as you should try to resolve the types within the variables first, but it may help you in testing.

Comment: Thanks all the problem is for one comma in $mileage = $product->mileage; returns 2,000 and $oilchnage shows 500,
when i remove comma it works 
Thank for your quick reply you are doing such a great job like your work <